# Oracle Select specific string from table plus following characters

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to select all rows from a table that contain a specific string, but then also return the following 4 characters after it that will usually be dynamic.

So basically I've got a table that looks like this

```
Column1 | Column2

CSE-001 | jdaosfjodas

CSE-002 | fjdaosfjdosj

GDS-001 | dskfjaodij

CSE-103 | fojdsiofj
```

Now, I want to Select all rows that start with CSE as well as the "-" and subsiquent three numbers that will follow, but those three numbers could be anything. So, based off the table above I'd want to return CSE-001, CSE-002, and CSE-103.

Sorry if this question is done horribly I'm relatively new to the site.
Thanks!

EDIT

@GordonLinoff Said almost exactly what I want, but what about instances where Column1 returns something like

```
Column1 | Column 2
GDE-002, CSE-101, GDE-003 | faosfd
```

In this case I would want to return that specific row, but only the "CSE-101" part of it.

Comment: Why are the columns labelled "Row1" and "Row 2"?  That is a bit disconcerting.

Comment: I removed PLSQL from the title, the question has nothing to do with PL/SQL.

Comment: What if Column1 is `CSE-2002`? Your requirement, interpreted strictly, is to return `CSE-200`. Or is that not possible in our data, what comes after the dash is always three digits? Is it *exactly* three digits, or could it be fewer? And if so, what is the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `regexp_like`.

For case-insensitive match use,

```
select * from tbl
where regexp_like(column1,'^CSE-[0-9]{3}$','i') 
--this query matches values like csE-101,CsE-001,cse-290 etc.
```

If you need case-sensitive match, use

```
select * from tbl
where regexp_like(column1,'^CSE-[0-9]{3}$')
```

Edit: Based on OP's edit after posting the answer above,

```
select * from tbl
where regexp_like(column1,'(^|\s|,)CSE-[0-9]{3}(,|\s|$)')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
select substr(col1, 1, 7), t.*
from t
where t.col1 like 'CSE-___%';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far! I've edited my post to hopefully make things a little clearer.